# What is the purpose of DLLs instead of static libraries

Tags: dll, static-libraries

I am using a library that that handles a variety of tasks related to game development. It comes with a compiled library files for both static linking and dynamic linking. Forgive my short-sightedness, but I ask, why would anyone use the DLLs over the static libraries when both are available? If using DLLs, it seems like this could introduce a variety of programs, like the DLLs being misplaced, lost, and it makes distribution of software less convenient. It could theoretically increase loading time for a program as well. The only practical benefit I see to using the DLLs is so maybe multiple programs can use the libraries, thus reducing the size of the programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that yes, DLLs can be shared among multiple programs.  Take for example kernel32.dll which is loaded into every user mode Windows application.  Windows can share the memory pages of kernel32.dll between all the running applications, but if it had instead been statically linked every application would have a duplicate copy of the same code pages.

Microsoft has a brief overview of the benefits of using DLLs here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681938(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

THIS- >

> ... thus reducing the size of the programs.

It also allows 3rd parties to update/fix functionality without having to recompile or release the dependent software.  Which is even more important...

Comment: Did not think of that. Are most software updates done in this sort of way?